# Oracle SQL: Filtering by ROWNUM not returning results when it should

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL I'm trying to run against an Oracle database:

```
SELECT *
FROM(SELECT crd.Request_ID,
        crd.Requested_Start_Date Scheduled_Start,
        crd.Actual_Start_Date Start_Date,
        crd.Actual_Completion_Date Finish_Date,
        crd.Status_Code
    FROM ((SELECT fcr.Request_ID,
                fcr.Requested_Start_Date,
                fcr.Actual_Start_Date,
                fcr.Actual_Completion_Date,
                fcr.Status_Code,
                fcr.Oracle_Session_ID,
                fcr.Responsibility_ID
            FROM Applsys.FND_Concurrent_Requests fcr
            WHERE fcr.Oracle_Session_ID IS NOT NULL)
        UNION ALL (SELECT xcr.Request_ID,
                xcr.Requested_Start_Date,
                xcr.Actual_Start_Date,
                xcr.Actual_Completion_Date,
                xcr.Status_Code,
                xcr.Oracle_Session_ID,
                xcr.Responsibility_ID
            FROM xxfnd.emr_FND_Concurrent_Requests xcr
            WHERE xcr.Oracle_Session_ID IS NOT NULL)) crd
    WHERE crd.Actual_Start_Date >= to_Date('06/01/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    ORDER BY 3, 1)
WHERE Rownum < (1000000 * to_Number(:X))
    AND ROWNUM >= (1000000 * (to_Number(:X)-1))
```

For `:X` set to 1, I get (as expected) the first 999,999 rows of data. However, when I set `:X` to 2, nothing is returned. This despite the fact that when I use `Select Count(*)` in place of `Select *` and drop the Where clause entirely the results indicate there are over 9 million records returned by the subquery.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `rownum` like this.  `rownum` is calculated when the values are actually returned from the query -- only when a row is returned.  Hence, the statement:

```
where rownum = 2
```

will never return a value, because there needs to a be a "1" before a "2".

If you are using Oracle 12+, you can use the `offset` clause with `fetch first <n> rows only`.  In earlier versions, you can use `row_number() over ()` to calculate a row number as a column and use that in the `where`.

Actually, your query already uses a subquery, so you can do something like:

```
select *
from (select . . .,
             row_number() over (order by Request_ID, Actual_Start_Date) as rn
      . . .
     ) t
WHERE rn < (1000000 * to_Number(:X) and)
      rn >= (1000000 * (to_Number(:X)-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you're using rownum in the outermost query, and you're expecting it to return rows if you specify that rownum >= <some number>. The only number that will ever satisfy that condition is 1, since rownum is assigned on the fly as rows are returned.

What you need to do instead is to assign the rownum in the main subquery and give it an alias, and then refer to the alias in the outer query - like so:

```
with main_results as (SELECT crd.Request_ID,
                             crd.Requested_Start_Date Scheduled_Start,
                             crd.Actual_Start_Date Start_Date,
                             crd.Actual_Completion_Date Finish_Date,
                             crd.Status_Code
                      FROM   (SELECT fcr.Request_ID,
                                     fcr.Requested_Start_Date,
                                     fcr.Actual_Start_Date,
                                     fcr.Actual_Completion_Date,
                                     fcr.Status_Code,
                                     fcr.Oracle_Session_ID,
                                     fcr.Responsibility_ID
                              FROM   Applsys.FND_Concurrent_Requests fcr
                              WHERE  fcr.Oracle_Session_ID IS NOT NULL
                              UNION ALL 
                              SELECT xcr.Request_ID,
                                     xcr.Requested_Start_Date,
                                     xcr.Actual_Start_Date,
                                     xcr.Actual_Completion_Date,
                                     xcr.Status_Code,
                                     xcr.Oracle_Session_ID,
                                     xcr.Responsibility_ID
                              FROM   xxfnd.emr_FND_Concurrent_Requests xcr
                              WHERE  xcr.Oracle_Session_ID IS NOT NULL) crd
                      WHERE  crd.Actual_Start_Date >= to_Date('06/01/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                      ORDER BY 3, 1)
SELECT *
FROM   (select Request_ID,
               Requested_Start_Date Scheduled_Start,
               Actual_Start_Date Start_Date,
               Actual_Completion_Date Finish_Date,
               Status_Code,
               rownum rn
        from   main_results)      
WHERE  rn < (1000000 * to_Number(:X))
AND    rn >= (1000000 * (to_Number(:X)-1));
```

Comment: Well that introduces an issue then. As I understand it, if I place ROWNUM in the subquery, it will be out of order since it would apply prior to the ORDER BY statement. In the grand scheme I can live with that, at least in this instance, but to get to the core principal, how would I go about (in Oracle 11) going through ordered (and thus non-overlapping) chunks of rows so that I can export query results to Excel without exceeding the row limit?

Comment: yes, sorry - I've confused myself :-) Rownum is applied *after* the filtering but *before* the ordering. Duh. You'd need an extra subquery to do the ordering then apply the rownum, before the outer query filters on the aliased rownum column. I'll update my answer to that effect, but basically if I were you, I'd go with Gordon's `row_number() over (order by Request_ID, Actual_Start_Date) as rn` suggestion, which means you don't need any extra subqueries, and you can get rid of the order by clause.